# Spring boot webclient 2gb xml data getting io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, streaming, spring-webflux

I am calling the api which returns XML response having data around 2gb , i am using Webclient to call xml data using below logic

```
private InputStream getUserResponse() throws UserClientException {


ClientResponse response = webClient
        .get()
        .uri(apiBaseURI)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
        .accept(APPLICATION_XML)
        .exchange()
        .block();
PipedOutputStream po = new PipedOutputStream();
final PipedInputStream pi;
try {
    pi = new PipedInputStream(po);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new UserClientException(e);
}
if (response != null) {
    int statusCode = response.rawStatusCode();
    if (statusCode != 200) {
        throw new UserClientException(new Exception(" Error from the client with statuscode " + statusCode));
    }


    Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux = response.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers())
            .doOnError(t -> {
                try (pi)
 {
                    log.error("Error in reading the data buffer body ", t);
                } catch (IOException io) {
                    log.error("Error closing input stream", io);
                }
            })
            .doFinally(s -> {
                try (po) {
                    log.debug("finally called ");
                } catch (IOException io) {
                    log.error("Error closing output stream", io);
                }
            });

    DataBufferUtils.write(dataBufferFlux, po)
            .subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer());
}
return pi;
}
```

But getting the below error

```
2021-07-08 21:08:32.456 INFO [user-svc,1d4e5fc0e89206ec,1d4e5fc0e89206ec,true] 13 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] a.w.WebClientCustomizerAutoConfiguration : timeout configuration: connectTimeout=PT1S, readTimeout=PT3S 2021-07-08 21:51:23.675 ERROR [user-svc,1d4e5fc0e89206ec,1d4e5fc0e89206ec,true] 13 --- [or-http-epoll-1] c.d.p.r.ingestion.crds.UserApiClient : Error in reading the data buffer body

io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null

2021-07-08 21:51:23.675 ERROR [user-svc,1d4e5fc0e89206ec,1d4e5fc0e89206ec,true] 13 --- [or-http-epoll-1] reactor.core.publisher.Operators : Operator called default onErrorDropped

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException Suppressed: io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null Caused by: io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null

2021-07-08 21:51:23.725 ERROR [user-svc,,,] 13 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.db.plcm.refdata.ingestion.exception.IngestionClientException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

with linked exception: [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2099781; columnNumber: 43; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.]] with root cause
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1471) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.endEntity(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:933) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.endEntity(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:562) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.endEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1504) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1925) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(XMLEntityScanner.java:1560) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2746) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216) [na:na] at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635) [na:na] at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:228) [jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3] at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:199) [jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3] at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:140) [jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3] at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:179) [jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3] at org.learning.reactive.CRDSXmlParserService.crdsXmlParser(CRDSXmlParserService.java:78) [classes/:na] at org.learning.reactive.UserApiClient.crdsService(UserApiClient.java:75) [classes/:na] at org.learning.reactive.UserTestController.getUser(UserTestController.java:19) [classes/:na] at org.learning.reactive.UserTestController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$172a955c.invoke() [classes/:na] at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) [spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88) [spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.learning.autoconfigure.observability.metrics.MetricsAspectSupport.callMetrics(MetricsAspectSupport.java:61) [spring-boot-starter-observability-2.3.4.jar:na] at org.learning.autoconfigure.observability.metrics.MetricsAspectSupport.recordDurationMetric(MetricsAspectSupport.java:50) [spring-boot-starter-observability-2.3.4.jar:na] at org.learning.autoconfigure.observability.metrics.MetricsAspectSupport.recordRequestDuration(MetricsAspectSupport.java:45) [spring-boot-starter-observability-2.3.4.jar:na] at org.learning.autoconfigure.observability.metrics.WebMetricsAspect.controllerMetrics(WebMetricsAspect.java:16) [spring-boot-starter-observability-2.3.4.jar:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [na:na] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) [na:na] at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644) [spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633) [spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) [spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) [spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) [spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) [spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.learning.reactive.UserTestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d1e9b738.getUser() [classes/:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [na:na] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [na:na] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) [na:na] at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) [spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) [spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) [spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:68) [brave-instrumentation-servlet-5.12.7.jar:na] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:87) [brave-instrumentation-servlet-5.12.7.jar:na] at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.java:139) [spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) [spring-boot-actuator-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [na:na] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [na:na] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
```

Still the data is there but it seems webclient is closing the connection, i see its printing 0 active and inactive channel connection

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the readtimeout configured in our code Webclient as 3 second due to that the error was ,increased the readtimeout  and it worked.

Comment: you could provide solution, how u did it